# How to append one csv file to another with python

Tags: python, csv

I have two .csv files that I need to either join into a new file or append one to the other:

filea:

```
jan,feb,mar
80,50,52
74,73,56
```

fileb:

```
apr,may,jun
64,75,64
75,63,63
```

What I need is:

```
jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun
80,50,52,64,75,64
74,73,56,75,63,63
```

What I'm getting:

```
jan,feb,mar
80,50,52
74,73,56
apr,may,jun
64,75,64
75,63,63
```

I'm using the simplest code I can find.  A bit too simple I guess:

```
sourceFile = open('fileb.csv', 'r')
data = sourceFile.read()
with open('filea.csv', 'a') as destFile:
    destFile.write(data
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get them to append 'horizontally' instead of 'vertically'.

Comment: Not in python at all, but there is a bash command exactly for that: `paste -d',' filea.csv fileb.csv`

Comment: You are passing strings to `writerow`, hence it is iterating over and comma-separating *characters*. You need to build a list representing each row `['Jan', 'Feb', ..., 'Jun']` and pass *that* to `writerow`.

Comment: Apologies, I edited my question and didn't realise I had already gotten comments.  Thanks very much everyone.

Comment: @Meelah, are you files equal length?

Comment: fredtantini - Thank you but I tried that and got the exact same result. @Padraic - the files I'm trying it with are equal length but I need something that could also work with files different in length and possibly containing blank fields.

Comment: ok, I will add something to pastebin

Comment: You're a star @Padraic, thanks a million!

Comment: @Meelah, no worries, question was reopened so added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open("filea.csv") as source1,open("fileb.csv")as source2,open("filec.csv","a") as dest2:
    zipped = izip_longest(source1,source2) # use izip_longest which will add None as a fillvalue where we have uneven length files
    for line in zipped:
        if line[1]: # if we have two lines to join
            dest2.write("{},{}\n".format(line[0][:-1],line[1][:-1]))
        else: # else we are into the longest file, just treat line as a single item tuple
             dest2.write("{}".format(line[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your files have the same length or at least contain blank fields:

filea.csv

```
jan,feb,mar
80,50,52
74,73,56
,,
```

fileb.csv

```
apr,may,jun
64,75,64
75,63,63
77,88,99
```

Script :

```
with open("filea.csv", "r") as source1, open("fileb.csv", "r") as source2, open("filec.csv","w") as dest:
    for line1, line2 in zip(source1, source2):
        dest.write(line1.strip()+','+line2)
```

If you need more compact version :

```
with open("filea.csv", "r") as source1, open("fileb.csv", "r") as source2, open("filec.csv","w") as dest:
    [dest.write(line1.strip()+','+line2) for line1, line2 in zip(source1, source2)]
```

Result (filec.csv):

```
jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun
80,50,52,64,75,64
74,73,56,75,63,63
,,,77,88,99
```